# Average, MIN , MAX in pandas for a column with string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column like this

```
User time  Column

User1 time1  44 db

User1 time2  55 db

User1 time3 43 db

User1 time4  no_available
```

How to calculate average, Min, MAX by just taking 44 55 43 (without db) and ignoring values like 'no_available' and 'no_power' for each user

Bonus, also how take last value of the day if user has for exemple 10 values for 10 times.

Regards,

thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all integers, you can use `str.extract()` to pull out the numbers. Then, return the mean, max, etc:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': {0: 'User1', 1: 'User1', 2: 'User1', 3: 'User1'},
 'time': {0: 'time1', 1: 'time2', 2: 'time3', 3: 'time4'},
 'Column': {0: '44 db', 1: '55 db', 2: '43 db', 3: 'no_available'}})
df['Numbers'] = df['Column'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
print(df['Numbers'].mean(), df['Numbers'].max())

Out [1]:
47.333333333333336 55.0
```

---

Example with `-`, `.`, or `,` in the number:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': {0: 'User1', 1: 'User1', 2: 'User1', 3: 'User1'},
 'time': {0: 'time1', 1: 'time2', 2: 'time3', 3: 'time4'},
 'Column': {0: '44 db', 1: '-45.32 db', 2: '4,452.03 db', 3: 'no_available'}})
df['Numbers'] = df['Column'].str.replace(',','').str.extract('(-?\d+.?\d+)').astype(float)
print(df['Numbers'])
0      44.00
1     -45.32
2    4452.03
3        NaN
Name: Numbers, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hello,thanks..... it's working but not for all cases, I have some negatives values also valus like that 42.03 db or -45.32 db

Comment: seem work with str.extract('(-?\d+.?\d+)'), it's correct ?

Comment: @mbooma I have updated my answer. You should also look for a comma just in case. I have included `.str.replace(',','')`. This replace migth be easier than a regex pattern with a comma. Please accept as answer by clicking the checkmark next to my solution and upvote if helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are the MAX and MIN for that column.
Give me like. :D

```js
import pandas as pd
a = ["user1","user1","user1","user1"]
a2 = ["time1","time2","time3","time4"]
a3 = ['45 db','55 db','43 db','no_available']
a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["user"])
a2 = pd.DataFrame(a2, columns=["time"])
a3 = pd.DataFrame(a3, columns=["column"])
data = pd.concat([a,a2,a3], axis=1)
data1 = list(data["column"])
h = []
for i in data1:
    try:
        if int(i[0:2]):
            h.append(int(i[0:2]))
    except:
        print(i)
max(h)
min(h)
```